# driver print brother DCP-195C ubuntu 13.04 32 bits

Tags: brother

I have a Brother DCP-195C printer ubuntu 13.04 32-bit scanner works but the printer does not print works but there is nothing on the paper out of the printer

Comment: cpoie is right but print and scan is not possible

Answer (score 0):

I'd comment this, but don't have the rep points so I'll do my best to answer your question:

I hate to ask, but does your printer have ink?  are the inkjet heads clean and clog free?

If you are sure that that are I'd try to print a test page via the printers internal software so that you can verify that the printer it self is okay.   If it is a network capable printer set it up to connect via your network, input the printers IP in your web browser and use the web interface to print a test page.